# Iterating through an object hashtable

Tags: javascript, hashtable

I am trying to use a hashtable so I can select a specific object stored in an array/object. However, I am having a problem looping through an object.

```
var pins= {};
pins[6] = '6';
pins[7] = '7';
pins[8] = '8';

$('#result3').append('<div>Size: ' + Object.size(pins) + '</div>');
for(var i = 0; i < Object.size(pins); i++) {
    $('#result3').append('<div>' + pins[i] + '</div>');
}
```

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/7TrSU/

As you can see in `TEST 3` which uses object `pin` to store the data, I am getting `undefined` when looping through the object `pin`.

What is the correct way for looping through `pin`?

**EDIT**

What happens if instead of just `pin[6] = '6'`, I make pin[6] = an object and I want to loop through the all their `id` properties? Actual code snippet of what I'm doing...

```
for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    markerId = json[i].listing_id

    // Place markers on map
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(json[i].lat, json[i].lng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                listing_id: markerId,
                position: latLng,
                icon: base_url + 'images/template/markers/listing.png',
    });

    markers[markerId] = marker;
}

for(var marker in markers) {
    console.log('marker ID: ' + marker.listing_id);
    mc.addMarker(marker);
}
```

The `console.log` above returns undefined, and if I do `console.log(marker)` instead, I get the value of `marker.listing_id`. Sorry I'm getting confused!

I managed to get it to work with `$.each(markers, function(i, marker){});` but why does the `for..in` above not work?

Comment: You are adding members at indexes 6, 7 and 8 but iterating from 0 to 2. A better strategy would be to iterate from `0` to `length-1` and test if the members exists before attempting to use it.

Comment: you are confusing _arrays_ with _objects_.

Comment: @c69—arrays are objects,  ;-)  The OP's problem is trying to access non existent properties.

Comment: @RobG yes, that's why i upvoted your comment )) but he is trying to access non-existent properties exactly because he is not understanding what he is doing.

Comment: What happens if instead of just `pin[6] = '6'`, I make pin[6] = an object and I want to loop through the all their property `id`? Updated original post.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Don't use a `for(i=0; i<size; i++)` loop. Instead, use:

1. [`Object.keys(pins)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get a list of properties, and loop through it, or
2. Use a `for ( key_name in pins)` in conjunction with [`Object.hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/HasOwnProperty) (to exclude inherit properties) to loop through the properties.

The problem of your third test case is that it reads the values of keys 0, 1 and 2 (instead of 6, 7, 8).

Answer (score 112):

```
var hash = {}
hash[key] = value

Object.keys(hash).forEach(function (key) { 
    var value = hash[key]
    // iteration code
})
```

Comment: The value variable is created after being used.

Answer (score 7):

Since you are using jQuery:

```
jQuery.each(pins, function (name, value) {
    $('#result3').append('<div>' + name + "=" + value + '</div>');
});
```

Comment: I used your method and it works the way I want it, but I don't understand why using `for..in` does not work as desired... Updated Original post...

Comment: Because you were using `for..in` to count the number of items, not to find out their names. Once you found out there were three items, you look at items named 0, 1 and 2 but the items were called 6, 7 and 8.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
for (var pin in pins) {
    $('#result3').append('<div>' + pin + '</div>');
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7TrSU/1/)

Comment: for ... in loops are sub optimum

Comment: @Raynos no, they aren't. Absence of `hasOwnProperty`, however, is.

Comment: @c69 `for ... in` is still suboptimum because it's less performant then `Object.keys`. `hasOwnProperty` is an expensive call

Answer (score 5):

```
function iterate(obj){
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    for(i in keys){
        doSomething(obj[keys[i]].id);
    }
}
```

This iterates over the `id` of all fields in any object

Answer (score -1):

The `pin` begins with 6 up to 8, but the for loop loops from 0 up to 3 (the length of the object). You need to loop from 6 up to `6 + the_size_of_the_object`. Something like this:

```
for(var i = 6, len = 6 + Object.size(pins); i < len; i++) {
  $('#result3').append('<div>' + pins[i] + '</div>');
}
```

---

Or something like this, this is what I like:

```
for( var i = 5; pin = pins[++i]; ) {
  $('#result3').append('<div>' + pin + '</div>');
}
```

Comment: That would be better if you added `if (pin.hasOwnProperty(i)) …` before attempting to use the member to weed out the nonexistent ones.